# How to find artifact id to put in pom.xml of a library if I know the import level path

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, package, pom.xml

I am starting to look into Java project and hence fairly new. I want to import a package which is mentioned as `import com.netflix.iceberg`. Here its documentation: https://netflix.github.io/iceberg/current/javadoc/

So I need to put this package in dependency tag inside pom.xml to install it. How do you find the artifactId of this package or any package going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *Central Maven Repository*, you can search over it using this [page >>](https://search.maven.org/search)

In your particular case you can try to search using keywords **iceberg** and **netflix**, but it will not give you needed result since **iceberg-api.jar** is not presented in the central repository.

---

From the URL you've added: https://netflix.github.io/iceberg/current/javadoc/ it is simple to find the project root, it will be: https://github.com/netflix/iceberg

Here it is visible that project is *Gradle* based. So as a workaround you can build needed jar and add it to your project using embedded *Maven* repository e.g. as it is shown [here >>](https://damienfremont.com/2016/01/08/maven-project-with-embedded-repository/)

---

To build jars please follow the steps below:

1. Download released project structure here: https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg/releases

   Currently there is only one version `0.2.0`
2. Since *Gradle Wrapper* is used the simplest thing to do is to run from the project root:

   `./gradlew tasks`

   Since `./gradlew` is a shell script, in case of using *Windows* OS you will need to use *Cygwin* or something similar.

   As a result of this command you will see all the *Gradle* tasks available for the *iceberg* project.
3. The one we needed is `assemble`, so just run:

   `./gradlew assemble`

   As a result of this command 7 jars will be built: *iceberg-api-0.2.0.jar*, *iceberg-common-0.2.0.jar*, *iceberg-core-0.2.0.jar*, *iceberg-orc-0.2.0.jar*, *iceberg-parquet-0.2.0.jar*, *iceberg-spark-0.2.0.jar*, *iceberg-runtime-0.2.0.jar*.

   *iceberg-api-0.2.0.jar* is located in the *PROJECT_ROOT\api\build\libs* directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where do you get the iceberg jar from?

Comment: @Atihska, unfortunately there is no jar available, what I've suggested is to download sources (and build them using *Gradle*) from the releases page: https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg/releases

Comment: @Atihska, project became public only in *December, 2017*, current version is *0.2.0* and their Google developer's group contains only 9 topics - so it is kind of "fresh" currently. I think this is the main reason there is no jar available.

Comment: So I opened the iceberg release in intelliJ. If I want to use that project in my project, how can I add it as a dependency? I tried to open 2 projects in the same window but it doesn't work and always replaces or opens in new window as a single project. Sorry, I am from the python/scripting world and fairly new to IntelliJ.

Comment: @Atihska, adjusted answer and added steps to build jar files too. In case it works for you please upvote the answer.

Comment: I saw a jar file for this project here: https://github.com/Netflix/iceberg/blob/master/examples/Convert%20table%20to%20Iceberg.ipynb as `%AddJar file:///home/user/iceberg-runtime-0.1.3.jar`. Can you tell if they have a jar already from this?

Comment: @Atihska, they pointed to a jar from the local directory `/home/user` (file URI scheme `file://` is used) - so it means that this example's manual assumes that jar was built earlier. Uploaded jars, please use this link to download: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06992488153288388106

Comment: So I was trying in another project to add iceberg dependencies. Just to clarify, if I just add maven dependencies in pom.xml as shown here: jitpack.io/#Netflix/iceberg/0.3.0, it doesn't install. The second option I tried was to create all the iceberg jars like you mentioned, but then how will pom.xml find them?It was working in my different environment so wanted to check for any missing steps while reproducing all steps to see how I got the above thing working.

Comment: @Atihska, please use [this link >>](https://damienfremont.com/2016/01/08/maven-project-with-embedded-repository/) to create _Embedded Maven Repository_. Embedded repository is something need to be created for each project you will have (it is a project subdirectory) and something that you will push to your version control system (_Git_, _SVN_, _Mercurial_, etc.).